# Material UI component `theme.spacing` not defined once built

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am building a Material-UI text editor using draft.js and wrapping all the functionality in Material-UI components.

I've gotten comfortable using `~3.9` but for this project decided to update to `4.0`. Maybe I'm missing something here but this usually works for me with no issues

```
const styles = theme => ({
  paper: {
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  ...
})


import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/styles"
...
export class EditorComponent extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(EditorComponent)
```

This works while running in a `webpack-dev-server` but when I build to javascript and attempt to import it into another project and use it I get this error in the console...

`Uncaught TypeError: theme.spacing is not a function`

I can't seem to find anything relevant googling this issue.

Here is the repo if looking at my build script would help

https://github.com/jrdn91/material-ui-rte

Comment: I would guess that the issue is in the project that you are importing this into. I suspect that the project you are trying to use this in is pulling in v3.9 of Material-UI.

Comment: @RyanCogswell No the project I'm pulling this into has been upgraded to 4.0 as well

Comment: Is there a repo you can share of a project that you are pulling this into where you get this error?

Comment: @RyanCogswell Pulled down the CRA example from the Material UI example projects page and spun it up pulling in my editor from NPM and I get the same errors
https://github.com/jrdn91/material-ui-rte-cre-example

Comment: It seems problematic that you have material-ui in the dependencies of both. I believe you will end up with two copies of material-ui (which could cause problems to manifest in confusing ways). In material-ui-rte, you should have the material-ui packages as **peer** dependencies so that the project using it fully controls which version of material-ui is used.

Comment: @RyanCogswell that's a good call, I will make that change. I actually ended up figuring out the answer to my question which I'll outline in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that pulling in `withStyles` or `makeStyles` etc. from `@material-ui/styles` does not include the default theme. There are wrapped version of these included in `@material-ui/core/styles` which do include the default theme.

So changing from `import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/styles"` to `import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"` will fix this issue.

Referenced from this page

https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/#material-ui-core-styles-vs-material-ui-styles